# What is the error in this SASS sentence?

Tags: sass

```
/* Sass Document */
```

$color_main: '#0671B2';

$color_secundary: '#019FAA';

a{color:$color_main}

Dreamweaver 2017 return this:

> body:before {   white-space: pre;   font-family: monospace;   content:
>   "Error: Invalid CSS after \"'#0671B2'\": expected expression (e.g.
>   1px, bold), was \";\"\A         on line 3 of
>   D:\Servidores\EasyPHP-12.1\www\2016\Buzzon\BuzzonWeb\assets\css\style.sass\A
>   \A 1: /* Sass Document */\A 2: \A 3: $color_main: '#0671B2';\A 4:
>   $color_secundary: '#019FAA';\A 5: \A 6: a{color:$color_main}"; }

Comment: Ommit the quotes `$color_main: #0671B2;`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, the file extension of my file was .sass the correct is .scss and problem solved!